# How to display the QR code in the "XtraReport" web report devexpress designer page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

Is it possible to display the QBCode barcode on the XtraReport devexpress designer page?

Need clarification,
After changing the barcode symbology option to "QRcode", it still remains in the normal barcode type and not changed to QRcode type barcode. If I go to the preview, it shows the QRcode on the preview page. But when I return to the designer page, it still being in the normal barcode.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Drag and drop the Xrbarcode on the designer page.
2. Change the "Symbology" field to the "QRCode" option.
3. Compare the QRcode in the designer and preview page.

Please check the below video link for your reference.

Video Link: https://ttprivatenew.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/anilkumar-aitechindia/attachments/19189873/TinyTake18-03-2022-11-32-46.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I had to do an image with an external source and used: [https://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d={DestinationURL}](https://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=%7BDestinationURL%7D)

This gave me the QR Code Image and seems to work seamlessly. As long as the Qrcode.kaywa.com stays around.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).